# How to find a tr which has a specific class attached and get the details of each td - jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, checkbox

Please check out this fiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/shaswatatripathy/y7jqb5hp/12/

HTML

```
<table id="tableID">
  <tr onclick="getdetails(this)">
  <th>checkbox</th>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr onclick="getdetails(this)">
  <td><input name="eachRow" type="checkbox"/> </td>
    <td>Alfreds </td>
    <td>Maria </td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr >
  <tr onclick="getdetails(this)">
   <td><input name="eachRow" type="checkbox"/> </td>
    <td>Centro </td>
    <td>Francisco </td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr onclick="getdetails(this)">
   <td><input name="eachRow" type="checkbox"/> </td>
    <td>Ernst </td>
    <td>Roland </td>
    <td>Austria</td>


</table>
```

CSS

```
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

.highlightRowSelected
{
  background-color:#e2e2e2;
}
```

Jquery

```
function getdetails(row) {
 $("#tableID tbody tr").each(function () {        
        $(this).removeClass("highlightRowSelected");        
    });    
    $(row).addClass("highlightRowSelected");


        }
```

what to modify getdetails(row) so that

1.whenever a row gets clicked its respective checkbox gets ticked

2.other row's checkboxes can be ticked , but that tick should not be a row click (important ) and obviously should not get highlightRowSelected class

3. if the row is clicked and has the checkbox ticked(by Point 1) then clicking on the checkbox should not uncheck the checkbox

only jquery allowed

Comment: I am voting to close this, as it is **too broad**. Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('#tableID input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function(event){
  // if tr has class "highlightRowSelected" do not let the click on the checkbox happen
  if($(this).closest('tr').hasClass('highlightRowSelected')) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    return;
  }
  
  // if click on checkbox do not go for click on the <tr>
  // which also happend, because the checkbox is inside <tr>
  event.stopPropagation();
});

$('#tableID tr').on('click', function(){
  if($(this).hasClass('highlightRowSelected')) {
      $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
      $(this).removeClass("highlightRowSelected");
  } else {
      // check if there is already a class highlightRowSelected
      // if so return (means, skip rest of code)
      // so in whole table only one .highlightRowSelected is allowed
      if($(this).closest('table').find('.highlightRowSelected').length >= 1){
          return;
      }
      $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
      $(this).addClass("highlightRowSelected");
  }
});
```

```css
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

.highlightRowSelected
{
  background-color:#e2e2e2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableID">
  <tr>
  <th>checkbox</th>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><input name="eachRow" type="checkbox"/> </td>
    <td>Alfreds </td>
    <td>Maria </td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr >
  <tr>
   <td><input name="eachRow" type="checkbox"/> </td>
    <td>Centro </td>
    <td>Francisco </td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><input name="eachRow" type="checkbox"/> </td>
    <td>Ernst </td>
    <td>Roland </td>
    <td>Austria</td>


</table>
```

Comment: all the rows are getting same class highlightRowSelected . always one row should get that class and check box tiked

Comment: @tripathy so you mean there is maximum one row which can get the class "highlightRowSelected" ?

Comment: @tripathy see updated answer where comment says `check if there is already a class highlightRowSelected` that's what you want ?

Comment: @tripathy did the answer work you? Please add a comment if not and explain what and why else please upvote and mark as accepted.

Comment: no , you can alos try , if i select one line , i cant select any other line

Comment: @tripathy well because I asked and you sayd yes: `there is maximum one row which can get the class` ready carefully trough the code, you should be able to turn that on and off